# AWS WAF Pricing For Blocked Requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos, amazon-waf

Simple question here: does AWS WAF charge for requests that it blocks?

The [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/pricing/) for WAF mentions that "you will be charged for the number of web requests processed by the web ACL". Does that mean **any** request that hits the WAF or is it only for requests that are allowed through? I can't seem to find the answer in the docs either.

I need to know because I plan to use WAF to rate-limit requests and try and prevent Denial of Wallet attacks. If all requests are charged for by WAF, then Denial of Wallet attacks would still be possible since these requests are being paid for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seen and processed` that mean any request that hits the WAF

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!