# AWS Cloudfront Prevent Denial of Wallet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, ddos

How can I prevent Denial of Wallet attacks against AWS Cloudfront?

Here's my specific situation: I have a Cloudfront distribution where Lambda@Edge functions serve web pages and API requests for my application. I need to rate-limit requests made to Cloudfront based on the IP address of the user. Without any kind of rate-limiting in place, it's possible for a malicious user to make millions of slow requests to the distribution that wouldn't be blocked by AWS's DDOS protections and which would lead to significant charges. This is especially important here since Lambda@Edge functions cost 3x as much as ordinary Lambda functions and don't come with a free tier.

It seemed practical to use AWS WAF in order to accomplish this. However, I [recently found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288717/aws-waf-pricing-for-blocked-requests) that WAF charges for all incoming requests, regardless of if they are blocked or not. So a Denial of Wallet attack would still be possible here.

Is there a method or a general strategy that I can implement here that doesn't involve AWS WAF?

The limits need to be very tight. Even paying $50 per month for malicious requests would be considered too high.

Answer (score 1):

`AWS Shield Standard` is free when you use Cloudfront and it automatically protects against common DDoS attacks. [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/pricing/)

If you want to use WAF to tighten the requests to your Lambda, you can setup caching for HTTP 403 responses in Cloudfront, so the attacker won't get their request past the Cloudfront cache.

You have to decide which one is on priority for you, your service being down or your bill going above your budget? If it's the first one, you can use WAF and `AWS Shield Advanced`.

If it's the second one, you can implement a request throttling method. For example, you can make use of incoming requests to EC2 instances are free. So you can implement a queue in a free tier EC2 instance that forwards the requests to your Lambda but drops the requests when the rate is higher than a defined threshold. Keep in mind that you get charged for outgoing requests from EC2 to your Lambda Edge.

OR you can implement another Lambda function before your Lambda Edge to keep track of which IP address sent how many requests. If it's past the threshold, respond with HTTP 403 and have that cached in Cloudfront. Then the next request from that IP address won't reach your Lambda. But again, keep in mind that you'll get charged for this additional Lambda.

The last resort is creating a billing alarm that notifies you when monthly charges reach $50 so that you can stop the costs before it goes high.

Answer (score 0):

`AWS Shield Advanced` includes DDoS cost protection, a safeguard from scaling charges as a result of a DDoS attack that causes usage spikes on protected Amazon EC2, Elastic Load Balancing (ELB), Amazon CloudFront, AWS Global Accelerator, or Amazon Route 53. **If any of the AWS Shield Advanced protected resources scale up in response to a DDoS attack, you can request credits via the regular AWS Support channel**.

Please note that, at the time of writing, [this service involves a monthly fee](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/pricing/) of **$3,000** per account, plus data transfer fees starting at $0.050 per GB.